# Random Location bounce when phone is steady

Tags: android, gps, location, android-gps

I know it's an old question and I've also researched many many post to get the clarity but there are somethings that I like to ask an expert.

Scenario - I'm using `mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,minTime,minDistance, this);`
to get location updates for my app. I'm using a criteria that is set `criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);` to get the provider.

What I want to know -

1. Does minTime and minDistance really affects the location capturing as I'm getting location on very less than both minTime and minDistance. If not then how can I get some little more accurate locations which follows the minTime and minDistance pattern?
2. When the device is at stationary place it shows some random location nearby. This leads to unwanted data which is not accurate. So how to avoid that?
3. After few idle hours, the GPS is facing very hard time in capture a location. What happened to it at that time.

Answer (score 0):

1. Not realy, even if you pick minTime=1s, and minDistance=0 or 1meter, and you will walk in circle(1-2 meters), you propably will get this same cordinates(I tried on 3 devices). It depence of configuration GNNS on each devices.
2. For more devices if position of new raw data from gps module will less than 3 meters, Android will not change position, even if new will be better.

exceptions devices, which can show RAW data: 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/gnss.html

PS. If you have some devices which show RAW data from modul GPS, you will see that in 1min location of all samples(600 for 10Hz), You will placed close each others(located in circle r=5cm), but if you go 2h later on this same place, You will see all attempts located focused further 2 meters than attemps from attempt first.